# php pdo code to search column array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

table name - animationmaster

column - animationdate ,type= varchar

column - animationno ,type= varchar

**Data present in each column are like below..**

**animationno = 300,301**

**animationdate = 300 - 23-03-2015,301- 23-04-2015**

When user search 300 then it display output 300-23-03-2015 from animationdate

When user search 301 then it display output 301-23-04-2015 from animationdate.

**I have no idea is this possible..or not...and if yes...i really no guesses how to achieve this...thanks for any help...to find solution**

plz help to get solution for this..array search

```
<?php   
$q = $_GET['q'];
$city = $database->getRows("SELECT animationdate  FROM animationmaster WHERE animationno = :animationno ", array(':animationno '=>"$q"));  
$info = array();
foreach($city as $row)
{       
    $generat = $row['animationdate'];           

    $info[] = array('date' =>$generat);
}
echo json_encode($info);
?>
```

Comment: What output/err you get now?

Comment: sir this return complete data of animationdate column like  300 - 23-03-2015,301- 23-04-2015  this...but i  need if i enter 300 then only return this 300 -23-03-2015 not all

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a database `SELECT` query based on user input using **PDO**:

```
<?php
$database= new PDO( "connection string goes here" );
$q = $_GET['q'];

$query=$database->prepare("SELECT animationdate FROM animationmaster WHERE animationno = :animationno");
$query->bindParam(':animationno', $q);
$query->execute();

$result = $query -> fetch();
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: The param is called $param not $q. Just pointing that out.

Comment: Okay thanks for the point I missed. I have updated the answer.

Comment: sir but this answer will not solve my problem....i also try this solution  but this also get same output here 300 - 23-03-2015,301- 23-04-2015. plz suggest me the answer for my question specific....its request to you..

Comment: plz suggest what to implement in above code to get proper solution as i want....

Comment: Just add the connection string, and let me know what you get now.(Follow the link if you are not clear about it-http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)